# Microsoft Access Row Merge

Tags: sql, merge, ms-access-2010

I'm hoping to get some help with merging data on Microsoft Access via a query. Currently I receive a data dump that contains many records. Most of these records are for the same job ie) same job id. I would like like combine them into a single row. Is this possible?

input:

```
jobid   jobdescription  processid   processdescription  processcreateddate
1234    Compliance  124               Accept              03/04/2014 10:32
1234    Compliance  135                Hold           03/07/2014 14:04
1234    Compliance  164                Review             03/04/2014 10:33
1234    Compliance  178               Complete             03/11/2014 8:21
```

Output:

```
jobid   jobdescription processdescription processcreateddate processdesc2  Proccreatedate2
1234    Compliance      Accept             03/04/2014 10:32    Hold       03/07/2014 14:04
```

etc...

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: You most certainly can do some sort of merge. But you are not providing the desired logic. What happens to the Review row and the Complete row?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show what progress you made before you got stuck.

Comment: The reason why I am attempting to merge the subsequent rows together is to better organize the data so I can pull specific information from the data via the criteria field. Currently, there are multiple rows of the same jobID with different process ID's indicating the flow that a job took.

I have attempted joining the table to itself by the JobID. However, when I try to pull specific information for the job description, and process description, multiple fields would return.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it looks like each process description should actually be a field name in your database.

Each process description should then contain a date.

Job ID--Job description--AcceptDate--HoldDate--ReviewDate--CompDate

1234----Compliance------01/10/14-----01/11/14---01/12/14-----01/01/15

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need a query that transposes rows into columns, or reshapes from long to wide.

Consider the following query with subquery and derived table nested in an aggregate query. Inner query counts number of processes per `jobid` and then outer query conditionally aggregates by `jobid` and `jobdescription` using calculated count:

```
SELECT jobid, jobdescription,    
       Max(IIF(processcount=1, pdesc, NULL)) As processdesc1,
       Max(IIF(processcount=1, pdate, NULL)) As prcoesscreateddate1,
       Max(IIF(processcount=2, pdesc, NULL)) As processdesc2,
       Max(IIF(processcount=2, pdate, NULL)) As processcreateddate2,
       Max(IIF(processcount=3, pdesc, NULL)) As processdesc3,
       Max(IIF(processcount=3, pdate, NULL)) As processcreateddate3,
       Max(IIF(processcount=4, pdesc, NULL)) As processdesc4,
       Max(IIF(processcount=4, pdate, NULL)) As processcreateddate4

FROM
       (SELECT t1.jobid, t1.jobdescription, t1.processid As pid,
               t1.processdescription As pdesc, t1.processcreatedate As pdate,
               (SELECT Count(*) FROM Processes t2 
                WHERE t1.jobid=t2.jobid AND t1.processcreatedate >= t2.processcreatedate) 
                As processcount
        FROM processes_dump t1) As derivedTable

GROUP BY t1.jobid, jobdescription;
```

**Output**

```
jobid   jobdescription  processdesc1    prcoesscreateddate1   processdesc2  processcreateddate2  processdesc3   processcreateddate3 processdesc4    processcreateddate4
1234       Compliance        Access     3/4/2014 10:32:00 AM       Review   3/4/2014 10:33:00 AM        Hold    3/7/2014 2:04:00 PM     Complete    3/11/2014 8:21:00 AM
```